# select with like return results with ( character

Tags: oracle, sql-like

I'm running plsql developer on oracle 11g.

My select with like return results with ( character although I didn't requested

```
 SELECT  * FROM TableA a where a.cofiguration like '%a_mobile_sw';
```

it return also records with configuration with values a_mobile_sw and also a_mobile(sw

How it return record with '(' character inside although not requested?

Comment: When using `LIKE`, the underscore matches any single character.

Comment: I bet you accidentally discovered bad data.  Surely `'a_mobile(sw'` is not a correct configuration name?  You may just want to leave the underscore as is in order to highlight that issue!  :-) At least do a select distinct on that column to see if there are other bad names in there, then bring that to someone's attention and be the data cleanup hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're searching for the underscore character, you need to escape it, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TableA a
where  a.cofiguration like '%a\_mobile\_sw' escape '\';
```

With the `like` comparison, `%` is a multiple character wild-card, and `_` is a single character wild-card, which is why you were seeing odd results. By escaping the underscore, you tell Oracle to treat it as an underscore rather than a wild-card.